# How do I sum the extracted value from a dictionary?

Tags: python

Say I have a dictionary of 10 keys with 10 values, and I want to extract 5 of the values from the dictionary.

Then I want to get the sum of the values that I extracted from the dictionary. How can I do that?

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
     "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
     "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
     "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
     "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    s = list(word)
    for char in s:
        numbers =[]
        numbers.append(score[char])
        print numbers
scrabble_score("overflaw")`
```

Now I need to sum the numbers from print, how do I do that?

Comment: And what's wrong with the `sum` function?

Comment: use ```sum``` function.What's your problem?can you show some code.

Comment: How do you select only 5 values? What's the condition?

Comment: please see edited question with code. thanks

Comment: The solution offered did what you wanted it to do from the beginning. The context of the question was just not provided in its first rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, it sounds like you want something simple like this:

```
    score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
        "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
        "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
        "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
        "x": 8, "z": 10}

    def scrabble_score(word):
        print sum(score[ch] for ch in word)

    scrabble_score("overflaw")
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a dictionary:

```
the_dict = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9}
```

and the keys for the values to be extracted:

```
the_keys = ['a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'h']
```

A sum(list comprehension), such as

```
a = sum([the_dict[key] for key, value in the_dict.items() if key in the_keys])
```

will return the sum of the values for the extracted keys. This can be put in a function in the following way:

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
     "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
     "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
     "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
     "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    numbers = [score[char] for char in list(word)]
    print(numbers)
    return sum(numbers)

the_word = list('hijab')
print(scrabble_score(the_word))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to iterate over the letters in the word and add the score from each, rather than iterate over the values and check if they're in the word? This way double letters will be missed and you'll end up with unnecessary loop iterations. Something like `sum([score[letter] for letter in word])`

Comment: @Trengot Absolutely :)

Comment: I do not understand the idea of down voting a post without feedback. It seems mean spirited to me. If you have time to hit the button, then you have time to include your constructive comments.

Comment: Just a comment from a few years ahead that I don't think readers appreciate. The original question was edited after this was posted.

Answer (score 0):

To extract values out of a dictionary from keys, you must do `score[char]` -> number, like `score['a'] -> 1`.

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
     "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
     "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
     "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
     "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    for char in word:
        numbers = []
        numbers.append(score[char])
        print numbers
scrabble_score("overflaw")
```

By the way, I edited your code so that it doesn't turn the string into a list... you can already iterate over strings.

Then,

> Now I need to sum the numbers from print, how do I do that?

Well, simply use the `sum()` function, like so:

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    numbers = []
    for char in word:
        numbers.append(score[char])
    return sum(numbers)
```

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) returns the sum of all the values in the list (link to documentation)

**EDIT:** Thanks to aaron for pointing out a bug, you cannot set numbers every time in the loop, it will make it empty every time.

P.S. learn to search the web + documentation before looking here; especially the documentation. Take a look at it.

Comment: You are re-initializing the list 'numbers' within the loop you are trying to append the value.